# How to update assembly version of c++ project in Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: c++, azure-devops

I have a c++ project solution which i am building using azure devops pipeline and i want to update the file version everytime my build is sucessful. I have found different extensions but none is working for me.

```
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "xxxxx"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "xxxx"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "xxxx"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.1.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "xxxxx"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "xxxxx"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "xxxx"
            VALUE "ProductName", "xxxxx"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.1.0.0"
        END
    END
```

this is how my .rc file looks where i set my default version and other things. I am looking for a way on how i can update fileversion and product version eveytime i build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Replace Text in Source Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles) extension. Just add two `Replace In Files Text By Text` tasks to replace the `FileVersion` and `ProductVersion` separately.

You can set your file and product version variables for the update. Also search the *.rc file by a pattern or specify the particular *.rc file in the Advance option.

Below YAML for your reference:

```
variables:
  FileVersion : 2.2.0.1  #This is just a sample, you can set and use the value dynamically like the build number. 
  ProductVersion : 2.3.0.2

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: ReplaceInFilesTextByText@2
  displayName: Replace-FileVersion
  inputs:
    parameterSearchDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    parameterSearchText: '"FileVersion", "1.1.0.0"'
    parameterReplaceText: '"FileVersion", "$(FileVersion)"'
    parameterTypeOfSearch: 'filesSearchPattern'
    parameterFilesPattern: '*.rc'

- task: ReplaceInFilesTextByText@2
  displayName: Replace-ProductVersion
  inputs:
    parameterSearchDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    parameterSearchText: '"ProductVersion", "1.1.0.0"'
    parameterReplaceText: '"ProductVersion", "$(ProductVersion)"'
    parameterTypeOfSearch: 'filesSearchPattern'
    parameterFilesPattern: '*.rc'
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Check-Modified-rc-file
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'cat $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test.rc'
```

As we can see the versions can be updated successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i have created a pwoershell script which uses regex to replace the fileversions